# Rename computer in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, hosts, sublime-text

How can I rename my computer? Renaming it in `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` does something weird. Before renaming it, I am able to open these files via sublime using

```
sudo subl /etc/hosts
```

but when I rename my Computer (using nano) and open any of these files using `subl`, I get this message:

```
No protocol specified

(sublime_text:20071): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
```

So I guess renaming in the above files is not the only thing I have to do.

PS: If I rename using sublime, after renaming one of the files, I get same message when I try to open other file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like a problem in Sublime Text.  You need to change the hostname using:

```
sudo hostname your-new-name
```

Then you need to add the new hostname to your `/etc/hosts` file with this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Find these lines and change the original name to your new hostname:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       your-new-name
```

To save in nano <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.
To exit from nano <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Restart the computer or all services that use the old name.